# Getting 'The application is disabled' for LinkedIn app and app disappeared from LinkedIn developer My App list

Tags: linkedin-api

We had created 2-3 apps in LinkedIn developer account and used it in auth0 tenant, suddenly we are getting message -
"The application is disabled".
And now there is only one app, can any one please suggest where apps gone away and why? How to republish those apps again?

Comment: This has happened to our Linkedin app as well. Will contact Linkedin for explanation.

Comment: In order to solve such a problem, I suspect you're going to need to improve your precision markedly. "2-3 apps" ?!! If you're not even sure how many apps you've created, you've probably got bigger problems. ;)